# Как включить топ-левел await

Tags: node.js, typescript

Всем привет.
Изучаю Тайпскрипт. Прочитал про топ-левел await, пытаюсь его включить в node приложении и никак не получается. Никаких толковых материалов в инете нет. Помогите, плиз.

Что я сделал.

- npm init
- npm i -D typescript @types/node ts-node
- потом еще Нодемон поставил.

Typescript - 5.3.3

Пытаюсь использовать await в index.ts.

- Он мне пишет: "error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher."
- Меняю в tsconfig target на es2022, module на node16.
- Он начинает писать "The current file is a CommonJS module and cannot use 'await' at the top level"
- Пытаюсь вставить в package.json type: module.
- Начинает писать "Unknown file extension ".ts"

И тут дальше уже заканчиваются идеи.
Помогите, пожалуйста, победить эту фигню.

tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
```

package.json

```
  "name": "ts-top-await-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [ ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.19",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
```

Запускаю npm run dev

Comment: в какой момент ты получаешь ошибку? если при запуске - что именно и как запускаешь? Если при компиляции - как компилируешь

Comment: Я запускаю через Нодемон, т.е. по сути это команда ts-node ./index.ts
Т.е. я отдельно не компилирую, это все ts-node делает автоматом.
Но насколько понимаю - это ошибки компиляции. Он не знает как собрать js и поэтому ругается.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос `tsconfig.json`  и `package.json`. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: можешь посмотреть вариант [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65257652/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy добавил tsconfig и package

Comment: и команду запуска тоже в вопрос перенеси

Comment: @Grundy добавил команду запуска

Comment: @Grundy не помогло ничего из поста, ссылку на который ты дал.

Comment: мб в module прописать es6? А сам type: moule в package.json не трогать

Comment: ну типо ecma script модули затребовать

Comment: @DenisLopatin запускаете на node 20 или node 18 и ниже?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Похоже, что у вас, как и у меня, стоит **Node 20** версии. Нашел ответ на ваш вопрос тут:

[Github ts-node issue: ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION on Node v20.0.0](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997#issuecomment-1943328149)

**Краткая выдержка:** ts-node сейчас имеет проблемы совместимости с Node 20.  Если вы хотите запускать код на Node 20 используя ts-node, то придется выполнять следующую команду, что лишает нас подробного стектрейса ошибки в случае ee возникновения:

```
node --loader ts-node/esm main.ts
```

---

Таким образом, чтобы заработал `top-level await`, вам нужно проделать следующие шаги:

1. В `tsconfig.json` установить следующие опции (остальные оставить прежними):

   ```
   "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es2022",
     "module": "Node16"
   }
   ```
2. в `package.json` установить `"type": "module"` и изменить скрипт `dev` на следующий:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "nodemon --exec \"node --loader ts-node/esm index.ts",
   },
   ```
3. Выполните `npm run dev`.

Для примера, оставлю тут свой тестовый `index.ts`:

```
async function waitForCookie(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('[INSIDE-FUNC] start cooking a cookie!');

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('[INSIDE-FUNC] cookie is ready, take it!!');
      resolve('Chocolate COOKIE!');
    }, 3000);
  })
}

const cookie = await waitForCookie();
console.log('[TOP-LEVEL] Received a cookie:', cookie);
```

Результат выполнения:

```
> ts-top-await-template@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon --exec "node --loader ts-node/esm index.ts

[nodemon] 3.1.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --loader ts-node/esm index.ts`
(node:26944) ExperimentalWarning: `--experimental-loader` may be removed in the future; instead use `register()`:
--import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register("ts-node/esm", pathToFileURL("./"));'
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[INSIDE-FUNC] start cooking a cookie!
[INSIDE-FUNC] cookie is ready, take it!!
[TOP-LEVEL] Received a cookie: Chocolate COOKIE!
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: Андрей, огромное спасибо.